# Replace a detected part of a sentence with * in sed

Tags: regex, sed

```
$ echo "name=hello 123" | sed 's/.*name=\(.*\)\s.*/\1/'
```

This is the command used to extract the word `hello` (string between = and whitespace) from the given text. Now I want to replace `hello` with `*****` using sed.

The output should be

```
name=***** 123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform substitution on matched portion only - `sed` doesn't provide a syntax for that, you could workaround using loop..

```
$ # tested on GNU sed, syntax might vary for other implementations
$ echo 'name=foo 123' | sed -E ':a s/(name=\**)[a-z]/\1*/; ta'
name=*** 123
$ echo 'name=hello 123' | sed -E ':a s/(name=\**)[a-z]/\1*/; ta'
name=***** 123
```

Or use `perl` which allows to use code in replacement section

```
$ echo 'name=foo 123' | perl -pe 's/name=\K[^ ]+/$&=~s|.|*|gr/e'
name=*** 123
$ echo 'name=hello 123' | perl -pe 's/name=\K[^ ]+/$&=~s|.|*|gr/e'
name=***** 123
$ # or construct a string based on length of matched portion
$ echo 'name=hello 123' | perl -pe 's/name=\K[^ ]+/"*" x length($&)/e'
name=***** 123
```

Comment: Thank you. yes this works, But this is replacing all the characters between =. Is there any way to define a range? like,
name=hello ;age=23
output name=***** ;age=23 (part between = and whitespace)

Comment: that is possible, but whole answer has to be changed.. please edit the question and change sample input and output.. also inform the other answerer.. in future, while asking question always add a sample that reflects your real use case to avoid this..

Comment: edited the question according to the expected output. The both options you have mentioned replace all characters after =. What I want is between = and whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo "name=hello" | sed 's/\(name\)=\(.\+\)/\1=*****/
```

If you want to replace each char with a *, see Sundeep's response.